# Click on Cancel doesn't work on first click. But it works on next attempt

Tags: c#, multithreading

There is a function which try to scan given folder. While scanning, there is a cancel button available to user. but it doesn't cancel the scanning on first attempt, however it succeed on next attempt.

Here's my code skeleton:

```
 private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;

 CallingMethod()
 {
   var cancelationToken = GetCancelationToken();
    Task.Run(() => { MethodA(true, stringVal, cancelationToken); }, cancelationToken);
 }

 internal void MethodA(bool isCreateNewRequested, string directoryPath, CancellationToken token)
    {
        bool sucess = true;            

        if (isCreateNewRequested)
            sucess = MethodB(directoryPath, token);

        if (token.IsCancellationRequested) return;

        //some more code
    }


    private bool MethodB(string directoryPath, CancellationToken token)
    {            
        var fileEntries = ProcessSubDirectories(directoryPath);
        var totalFileCount = fileEntries.Count;

        foreach (var fileEntry in fileEntries)
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested) break;

            //dosomething here
        }

        if (token.IsCancellationRequested) return false;

    }

 private CancellationToken GetCancelationToken()
    {          
        _tokenSource?.Cancel();
        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        return _tokenSource.Token;
    }
```

Comment: Do you use one instance of class which contains this logic? And I don't see the code which actually triggers cancellation on click.

Comment: @mtkachenko It will be called on a button click. And yes! I am using only one instance.

Comment: How do you check that `it doesn't cancel the scanning on first attempt`?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to create simple cancellation token:

```
CancellationToken cToken = new CancellationToken();
```

just like that. This token has to be passed to async method, and then:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cToken);
```

Then use this cts.

```
if(cts.Cancelled) //written from head, so there may be other way to check it
    cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

or:

```
cts.Cancel(true); //if you want to cancel manually something
cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

You cannot just return. You have to throw to cancel the operation.

Comment: Why do you use `CreateLinkedTokenSource`? It's useful when you want to combine few tokens like here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/how-to-listen-for-multiple-cancellation-requests

Comment: I have read it some time on microsoft while looking for manual cancellation. But I can't find now the source.